# How to Import 1 gig + /big database in phpmyadmin with ubuntu, terminal or in the gui itself is ok

Tags: database, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

icant Import a database the size of 1 gigabyte in phpmyadmin. and iam new in ubuntu operating system. help guys

## Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin (or any other web-based method) is going to suffer from the PHP resource limits in cases of a file this large. The most reliable way is to use the `mysql` command-line tool.